# Rails - How to Pass Parameter to Different Controller to edit Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, parameters

I have a Store class that I want to enter in Toy ID into a simple form to attach the Toy object to that store. The only thing is passing through is params[:id], not params[:toy_id]

Store _form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag({controller: "toys", action: "update"}, method: "post") do %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:toy_id) %>
    <%= submit_tag("Update") %>
<% end %>
```

After clicking submit, it should go to ToysController with two parameters: 1) params[id] which is store id and 2) params[:toy_id]

ToysController=>update:

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    store = Store.find(params[:id])
    toy = Toy.find(params[:toy_id])
    toy.store_id = store.id
    toy.save

    if @toy.update(toy_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @toy, notice: 'Toy was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @toy }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @toy.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: heebee313, try my answer. It should work or at least take you very close to the solution. Let me know if you have any other question. If that does not work, please update your question with how does the `params` look like after that change. I will update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `form_tag`, you have to pass the value of the `toy_id` as well. Try something like this:

```
<%= text_field_tag(:toy_id, @toy.id) %>
```

You may want to use `form_for` instead of `form_tag`. Because, the `form_for` method handles grabbing values from your model, and will try to route the form to the appropriate action. 
With `form_tag` you are responsible for everything as it makes no assumptions about what you're doing.

Also, for updating record, you should use `put` method instead of `post` method. `post` is for creating records.

#### Another method:

You should also be able to send the `toy_id` to the controller using a `hidden_field_tag` like this:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :toy_id, @toy.id %>
```